# Calculating AVG DIFF btw timestamps GROUPED BY other field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a "track_events" table that tracks pings to beacons (regions) in the following format:

```
id  region  triggered_at
1234  abc  2016-03-04 21:07:18.817+00
1235  def  2016-03-04 22:04:11.817+00
1236  abc  2016-03-05 01:21:43.817+00
1237  def  2016-03-05 07:44:43.817+00
1238  abc  2016-03-05 11:34:45.817+00
1238  ghi  2016-03-05 14:09:55.817+00
1238  abc  2016-03-06 02:12:10.817+00
```

I'm trying to build logic to estimate if a beacon (region) has stopped generating data by determining the [avg. time difference between triggers] and then generating a list of all regions where the [avg. time difference btw triggers] < [current time - last trigger]. My logic is as follows:

1. use a LAG type f(x) to generate a "prev_triggered_at" field;
2. find the AVG time difference between "triggered_at" and "prev_triggered_at" fields;
3. generate list of regions where this avg < [current time - last ping]

Any suggestions on how to write this query?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to work on temptable to make your life easier and do anything you need step by step.
For each step add a column to throw in the calculation or extract from query. e.g. prev_triggered_at , AVG,Diff etc.

Step1: use the following script:

```
      select a.id, a.region, a.triggered_at
           , max(b.triggered_at) as  prev_triggered_at
      from track_events a 
      inner join track_events b 
      on a.region=b.region
      and a.triggered_at>b.triggered_at
      group by  a.id,a.region,a.triggered_at
```

Step 2: simply add an AVG column to the temptable and calculate the average that you want using the avg() function. I would provide the query but I am not sure I get it right from the information you are giving.

Step 3: select statement with a where clause as you have described it since you will have all your information the same row.